# Lyapunov Exponent Code Output Nolds

Tags: python, numpy

I am researching about Lyapunov exponents, and that the Rosenstein algorithm can be used to calculate the maximum exponent. I am using the nolds package in python. I also know that Lyapunov exponents alone cannot be used to determine if a system is chaotic or periodic. Here is the following example code I am using:

```
import numpy as np 
import nolds
rwalk = np.cumsum(np.random.random(1000))
nolds.lyap_r(rwalk)
```

This gives the following output:

```
array([5.94316837e+00,   9.23215127e-06])
```

Why are there two different numbers? I have read the documentation and I do not see why the output is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the nolds module, I have different result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run your codes and I got only one value `-6.995882306965874e-06`

Answer (score -3):

I think you are estimate the whole spectrum of Lyapunov exponents. To estimate the largest Lyapunov exponent you can use nolds,lyap_e()